# Why would google tests compile but not be able to see my project sources?

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

Why would google tests compile but not be able to see my project sources?

Here's the error that I'm getting:

```
$ cmake . && make && make test
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: mars_rover
Scanning dependencies of target mars_rover
[  8%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/mars_rover.dir/src/rover.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable build/bin/mars_rover
[ 33%] Built target mars_rover
[ 41%] Built target gtest
[ 50%] Built target gtest_main
Scanning dependencies of target mars_rover_TEST
[ 58%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/mars_rover_TEST.dir/test/test_mars_rover.cpp.o
mars_rover/test/test_mars_rover.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'src/directions.h' file not found
#include "src/directions.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/mars_rover_TEST.dir/test/test_mars_rover.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/mars_rover_TEST.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Here's how I've got my project laid out:

```
$ tree {src,test,lib} -L 1
    src
    ├── directions.cpp
    ├── directions.h
    ├── main.cpp
    ├── plateau.cpp
    ├── plateau.h
    ├── point.h
    ├── rover.cpp
    └── rover.h
    test
    ├── input1
    ├── output1
    ├── test_main.cpp
    └── test_mars_rover.cpp
    lib
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── gtest-1.7.0
```

And here's my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

# Options. Turn on with 'cmake -Dtest=ON'.
option(test "Build all tests." ON)

set(PROJECT_NAME mars_rover CXX)
project(${PROJECT_NAME})

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -Wall -Werror")

file(GLOB_RECURSE PROJECT_SOURCES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_SOURCES})
SET(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/build/bin)
SET(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/build/lib)

if (test)

  add_subdirectory(lib/gtest-1.7.0)
  enable_testing()
  include_directories(${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${gtest_SOURCE_DIR})

  # finding test sources
  file(GLOB_RECURSE TEST_SOURCES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/test/*.cpp ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp)
  add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_TEST ${TEST_SOURCES})

  # link to gtest
  target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_TEST gtest gtest_main)

  add_test(CardinalDirectionTests ${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}/${PROJECT_NAME}_TEST --gtest_filter=MarsRoverTest.CardinalDirectionTests)
  add_test(RelativeDirectionTests ${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}/${PROJECT_NAME}_TEST --gtest_filter=MarsRoverTest.RelativeDirectionTests)

endif()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your test executable can't find 'src/directions.h' since its parent (`${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}`) hasn't been added to the `include_directories` call.  Just adding it should work.

However, I can see a few other minor points in your setup.  Running through your CMakeLists.txt, here are the changes I'd make:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
```

If you can specify 2.8.12 as the minimum, you have access to the more useful [`target_include_directories`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_include_directories.html) command.  Where `include_directories` is a bit of a blunderbuss approach, `target_include_directories` allows you to specify search paths just for that specific target.  If you specify these as `PUBLIC` or `INTERFACE`, then subsequent targets which link to this one will automatically inherit these search paths too.

In a similar vein, you could look at using [`target_compile_definitions`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_compile_definitions.html) and [`target_compile_options`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_compile_options.html).

---

<strike>`set(PROJECT_NAME mars_rover CXX)`

`project(${PROJECT_NAME})`</strike>
`project(mars_rover)`

The `project` command *sets* the variable `PROJECT_NAME`, so your `set` command has little use here.  And CMake will detect that this is a C++ project by virtue of the source file suffixes.

---

By including all your sources in two separate targets (the main exe and the test exe), these will all be compiled twice.  To avoid this inefficiency, I'd make a library of all your sources in "/src" except "main.cpp" and then have an exe which *only* has main.cpp and links to this library.

Also, using `file(GLOB ...)` or `file(GLOB_RECURSE ...)` is discouraged as a means of gathering source lists.

<strike>`set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -Wall -Werror")`

`file(GLOB_RECURSE PROJECT_SOURCES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp)`
`add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_SOURCES})`</strike>

```
# No need to include .h files, but they show up in IDEs like Xcode if you do.
set(libSources
    src/directions.cpp src/directions.h
    src/plateau.cpp src/plateau.h
    src/point.h
    src/rover.cpp src/rover.h
    )
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}_LIB ${libSources})

# Anything linking to this will automatically have ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
# added to the compiler's search paths since it is PUBLIC.  Prefer
# ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} to ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} in case this project is not
# the top-level one.
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}_LIB PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})

# Use generator expressions to conditionally apply the flags to Unix and Debug
# builds.  Anything linking to this will automatically have these flags also
# applied since they are PUBLIC.
target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME}_LIB PUBLIC
                       $<$<BOOL:${UNIX}>:-Werror -Wall $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:-g>>)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_NAME}_LIB)
```

---

For the test, it looks like you have 2 or maybe 3 `main` functions - that's going to be a problem :-)  `gtest_main` is a small helper which provides a `main` function which calls the required gtest functions to invoke the tests.  I'm guessing you've also got `main` in "test/test_main.cpp" and since you're currently including all your "src/" files, I suppose you've also got a `main` in "src/main.cpp".

By splitting the `mars_rover` target into a lib and exe, you can just link to the lib and avoid explicitly excluding "src/main.cpp" from the test.  I can't tell whether you want to use your own "test_main.cpp" or use gtest's helper - I've assumed the latter:

<strike>`include_directories(${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${gtest_SOURCE_DIR})`

`file(GLOB_RECURSE TEST_SOURCES ...)`

`add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_TEST ${TEST_SOURCES})`

`target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_TEST gtest gtest_main)`</strike>

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_TEST test/test_mars_rover.cpp)

# Only bring gtest's include path into scope - its src dir is not designed to
# be public 
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}_TEST PRIVATE
                           ${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_TEST ${PROJECT_NAME}_LIB gtest gtest_main)
```

---

Finally, there's no need to specify the full path to the test exe if you use the following syntax:

```
add_test(NAME CardinalDirectionTests
         COMMAND ${PROJECT_NAME}_TEST
             --gtest_filter=MarsRoverTest.CardinalDirectionTests)
add_test(NAME RelativeDirectionTests
         COMMAND ${PROJECT_NAME}_TEST
             --gtest_filter=MarsRoverTest.RelativeDirectionTests)
```

Comment: That's a fantastic answer and it does highlight my issue(s).  I was able to resolve them this evening, and now it works quite well.  I appreciate your answer!

Comment: Very minor nitpick: You might want to use [`PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR.html) instead of [`CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR.html) for specfifying the inlcude dir. The former will keep working even if your CMakeLists is pulled in by another project via `add_subdirectory`, while the latter might break in that case.

Comment: This should be part of a guide on how to write proper `CMake` files, which seems to be lacking on the web.